# remember me in laravel auth working even if not checked

Tags: laravel, remember-me, laravel-authentication

Using laravel 5.7 with Auth. every thing is Ok just one problem. The rememberMe checkbox is working even if not checked!. if i login to website without checking the remember me and close the browser, open it, it automatically logins. i want automatically login only if remember me is checked.

SOLVED:
actually there was no problem. the laravel remembers users login for 2 hours even if not checked the "remember me" checkbox. and if check the remeber me, laravel remembers for 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed the problem, and by doing some research, I was able to find a solution

In the `auth/login.blade.php` view, you need to fix one

```
<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

You need to change the condition like this

`{{ old('remember') !== null ? 'checked' : '' }}`

Hope this help you

Comment: thank you but this wasn't the problem. I found the solution edited the question.

Comment: @E.B can you tell me the solution